# Redux + Typescript + typesafe-actions:

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Having an issue using Typescript 3.2.2 with typesafe-actions 3.0.0. I have created an example below showing the issue.

Basically in my reducer, `payload` is not defined on `action` because some of my actions are of type `EmptyAction`, which does not define a `payload` property. If I change these to have an empty payload (`{}`), then `payload` is defined for all actions, but now the type of `payload` is not being determined based on the `type` of the action (in the reducer).

I believe I've followed the [Mighty Tutorial](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions#behold-the-mighty-tutorial) correctly.

Working example: https://github.com/JoshMcCullough/react-ts-test

**action-types.ts**

```
export default {
    GET_PROFILES_REQUEST: "GET_PROFILES_REQUEST",
    GET_PROFILES_SUCCESS: "GET_PROFILES_SUCCESS",
    GET_PROFILES_FAILURE: "GET_PROFILES_FAILURE",
};
```

**actions.ts**

```
import { action } from "typesafe-actions";
import { ApiErrorResponse } from "../../app/api/ApiErrorResponse";
import { Profile } from "../../app/models/Profile";
import ActionTypes from './action-types';

export const getProfilesRequest = () => action(ActionTypes.GET_PROFILES_REQUEST); // EmptyAction<string>
export const getProfilesSuccess = (profiles: Profile[]) => action(ActionTypes.GET_PROFILES_SUCCESS, { profiles }); // Action<string, { profiles: Profile[] }>
export const getProfilesFailure = (error: ApiErrorResponse) => action(ActionTypes.GET_PROFILES_FAILURE, { error }); // Action<string, { error: ApiErrorResponse }>
```

**reducer.ts**

```
import { ActionType, getType } from "typesafe-actions";
import * as Actions from './actions';
import { Profile } from "../../app/models/Profile";

// reducer
export type ProfileAction = ActionType<typeof Actions>;

export type State = {
    profiles: Profile[];
    errorMessage: string;
    loading: boolean;
};

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    profiles: [],
    errorMessage: null,
    loading: false,
};

export default (state: State = INITIAL_STATE, action: ProfileAction): State => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case getType(Actions.getProfilesRequest): return {
            ...state,
            loading: true,
        };

        case getType(Actions.getProfilesSuccess): return {
            ...state,
            profiles: action.payload.profiles,
            // ERROR: Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'EmptyAction<string> | PayloadAction<string, { profiles: Profile[]; }> | PayloadAction<string, { error: ApiErrorResponse; }>'.
            // Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'EmptyAction<string>'. [2339]
            loading: false,
        };

        case getType(Actions.getProfilesRequest): return {
            ...state,
            errorMessage: action.payload.error.message,
            // ERROR: Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'EmptyAction<string> | PayloadAction<string, { profiles: Profile[]; }> | PayloadAction<string, { error: ApiErrorResponse; }>'.
            // Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'EmptyAction<string>'. [2339]
            loading: false,
        };

        default: return state;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my action types were not defined as `const`! I had overlooked it, since I'm upgrading an existing codebase.

The solution is to make sure they're `const`s:

**action-types.ts**

```
export const GET_PROFILES_REQUEST = "GET_PROFILES_REQUEST";
export const GET_PROFILES_SUCCESS = "GET_PROFILES_SUCCESS";
export const GET_PROFILES_FAILURE = "GET_PROFILES_FAILURE";
```